# About the DECISION TREE and accuracy rate

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to convert the information that has been converted to 0101 to the original text And to calculate the accuracy rate .

Is my code able to do this? >>>"Use Python and the decision tree suite to write programs for decision tree model training and model performance evaluation."

I want to know how to do that.
 [here is my data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data)

```html
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
myData = open(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\all.csv')
reader = csv.reader(myData)
headers=next(reader)
print (headers)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
balance_data = balance_data.apply(le.fit_transform)


print ("tt,",balance_data)
Y = balance_data.values[:,0]
X = balance_data.values[:, 1:7]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size =0.3, random_state = 100)
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini",
                               max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf=5)

clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)

DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=3,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=5,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            presort=False,  splitter='best')

clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", random_state = 100,
 max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)
clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train)
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='entropy', max_depth=3,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=5,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            presort=False,  splitter='best')


with open('ppp','w') as f:
    f=tree.export_graphviz(clf_entropy,out_file=f)
   
 
y_pred_en = clf_entropy.predict(X_test)
y_pred_en

print("Accuracy is ", accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_en))

y_pred_en = clf_entropy.predict(X_test)
y_pred_en

print("Accuracy is ", accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_en))
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_en)

print("asd",accuracy)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njxaS.png)

Comment: I don't really understand what your goal is. Furthermore, it would be useful if you explain what you already have tried and what went wrong. Just dumping your data and source code doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: I have upload my  DECISION TREE imgs , you can see the DECISION TREE  show X[5] but its not useful i want X[5]= heards in my data like doors

Comment: i would suggest you to convert the data into numerical form instead of categorical,: then apply  DecisionTreeClassifier from sklearn.tree